# How to run inference on inception v3 trained models?

Tags: tensorflow, imagenet

I've successfully trained the inception v3 model on custom 200 classes from scratch. Now I have ckpt files in my output dir. How to use those models to run inference?

Preferably, load the model on GPU and pass images whenever I want while the model persists on GPU. Using TensorFlow serving is not an option for me.

Note: I've tried to freeze these models but failed to correctly put output_nodes while freezing. Used `ImagenetV3/Predictions/Softmax` but couldn't use it with feed_dict as I couldn't get required tensors from freezed model.

There is poor documentation on TF site & repo on this inference part.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the right track, you don't really do anything different at inference time as you do at training time except that you don't ask it to compute the `optimizer` at inference time, and by not doing so, no weights are ever updated.

The save and restore guide in tensorflow documentation explains how to restore a model from checkpoint:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

You have two options when restoring a model, either you build the OPS again from code (usually a `build_graph()` method) then load the variables in from the checkpoint, I use this method most commonly. Or you can load the graph definition & variables in from the checkpoint if the graph definition was saved with the checkpoint.

Once you've loaded the graph you'll create a session and ask the graph to compute just the output. The tensor `ImagenetV3/Predictions/Softmax` looks right to me (I'm not immediately familiar with the particular model you're working with). You will need to pass in the appropriate inputs, your images, and possibly whatever parameters the graph requires, sometimes an `is_train` boolean is needed, and other such details.

Since you aren't asking tensorflow to compute the optimizer operation no weights will be updated. There's really no difference between training and inference other than what operations you request the graph to compute.

Tensorflow will use the GPU by default just as it did with training, so all of that is pretty much handled behind the scenes for you.

Comment: I'm currently using slim to train and eval the model. This adds a lot of abstraction to really understand how things are working on the model level. I'll dig deep into it and report back.

I've tried both the ways. Using ckpt.meta and ckpt.data files to load net architecture and weights. Couldn't go beyond this point. 
And froze the model using mentioned output node and gone through all available ops in frozen model but couldn't go further.

Comment: Ah, maybe asking the question specifically of the abstraction framework rather than of the tensorflow community will get you the answer you need. I can't help any with that framework, I'm merely a tensorflow purist. :)

Comment: I've managed to freeze the model with analyzed frozen graph and all its operations. Downloaded pretrained inception v3 .pb model has an op named "/input" and my trained model doesn't have that op. It has "fifoqueue" and stuff.

Any idea how to add a placeholder input op? Is it added while training the net or can we add it to the final graph.pb file?